# Windows batch: Reset Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to collect first file from the directory then process the file. But at the second time when the running and processing the batch file I am unable to store the values in the variable for the file name

Below is the sample code:

```
for /R C:\abcde_efghij\ab_abcabca %%i IN (*.*) DO (
set filename=%%i
 set newname=%filename:~14%
 set transname=%filename:~25%
goto tests
)
:tests
echo %filename%
echo %newname%
echo %transname%
```

I am sure we have to use something called `SETLOCAL` but I am unable to make it in the above code.

Any Help!

Comment: the famous [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid percent expansion inside of blocks, also FOR blocks, as the expansion only occours only once when the block is parsed.

```
for /R C:\abcde_efghij\ab_abcabca %%i IN (*.*) DO (
 set filename=%%i
 goto :tests   # Get only the first file
)
exit /b

:tests
set newname=%filename:~14%
set transname=%filename:~25%
echo %filename%
echo %newname%
echo %transname%
exit /b
```

As @Stephan noted, you could also use delayed expansion inside blocks.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R C:\abcde_efghij\ab_abcabca %%i IN (*.*) DO (
  set filename=%%i
  set newname=!filename:~14!
  set transname=!filename:~25!

  goto :tests   # Get only the first file
)
```

Comment: for "collect first file", the `goto` is intended to break the loop.

Comment: @Stephan yes. I modified `goto` instead of `call`. Thanks

Comment: @Stephan You are right, I should read the texts more carefully